# How to create configurable product programmatically, without object manager?

Tags: magento, magento2

All the answers in SO/Google only shows up how to do this WITH object manager. And as most people know, it isn't recommended to use object manager.

So, how do I create a configurable product WITHOUT object manager?

This code below is as far I have gotten:

```
public function __construct(ProductInterfaceFactory $factory,
                            ProductRepositoryInterface $repository)
{
    $this->repository = $repository;
    $this->factory = $factory;
}

public function setEntity($source)
{
    $product = $this->factory->create();
    $product->setSku($source->getId());
    $product->setName($source->getDescription());
    $product->setPrice($source->getUnitPrice());
    $product->setVisibility(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    $this->repository->save($product);
}
```

Comment: Yes it is not recomended to use Object Managers in M2. Use Repositories and Factory pattern as per required. Btw you want to create a configurable product programmitically in M2?

Comment: Yes. Any examples?